# Is there a way to check that all Cargo.toml files in a workspace specify the exact same version of a crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have several crates inside a workspace, all of which depend on the
outside crate **X** from crates.io. I use explicit versions to make sure that build is reproducible and not get random failures on CI.

When **X** has a bugfix and version bump, I need to find and fix all of its mentions in all sub-crates of my workspace.

I can not use the `replace` section in the workspaces Cargo.toml because I use also sub-crates of my workspace as separate crates in other projects.

Is there a way to check that **X** inside all Cargo.toml of my sub-crates have the same version? I thought about running a Python script inside build.rs, but maybe there is a simpler solution?

Comment: *I use explicit versions to make sure that build is reproducible* — that's **not** the idiomatic solution. Please review what the [Cargo.lock](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html#cargotoml-vs-cargolock) file is for.

Comment: @Shepmaster Idiomatic solution not really help for many reasons. For workspace only one Cargo.lock exists for several crates, part of them libraries, part of them executables. Even if I use workspace Cargo.lock, I need first build to generate it, to generate it I need specify dependicies of each sub-crates, and after that I need manage this dependicies which move us to my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you, there may be a language barrier. What I'm trying to convey is that you should not have `X = "=1.2.3"` in any Cargo.toml file. Instead, you'd say `X = "1.2.3"`. Version 1.2.3 will be recorded in the Cargo.lock file initially. When a bug fix to X is released, you type `cargo update`, which will resolve all the dependencies again and change the Cargo.lock file to have 1.2.4. Every crate in the workspace will have been upgraded to use the same updated version. That's the beauty of semantic versioning + lockfiles.

Comment: @Shepmaster This is not exactly how it in real life. Bug fix may be with API change, so it from `1.2` become `1.3`, I update dependicies of one subcrate, fix compile time error, do `cargo update`, after that I want type `cargo --all check-that-all-have-same-dependicies-versions` so it automaticaly find other packages that still depend on `1.2`, so I can fix them. At now after `cargo update` I only have one sub-crate that depend on bug fixed version, and other that depend on buggy version of package?